# not found 404 for updating

Tags: java, postman, put

Im tried to send the score to database by giving the email of user in the url this  is the result in postman :

```
url:http://localhost:8085/quiz?email=user@gmail.com&score=100

"timestamp": "2021-05-22T13:03:15.451+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/quiz"
```

my method Updatescore in the controller:

```
    @PutMapping(path = "/quiz")
    public void Updatescore(@RequestParam(required = true) String email, @RequestParam(required = true) int score) {
        paserv.updatePatientScore(email, score);
    }
}
```

my method updatePatientScore in the service:

```
    @Transactional
    public void updatePatientScore(String email, int score) {
        patient p = paRepo.findByEmail(email);
        // .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("student with id" + studentID +
        // "does not exist"));
        if (score != 0) {
            p.setScore(score);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Does your `@RestController` have `@RequestMapping` annotation?

Comment: Please [edit] the post and provide the request you sent (e.g. as `curl`-command). --- `PUT` seems unfitting and may be replaced with the `POST` verb since  [as per IETF RFC 7231, Section 4.3.4](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.4): "*... A successful PUT of a given representation would suggest that a subsequent GET on that same target resource will result in an equivalent representation being sent in a 200 (OK) response. ...*"

Comment: It is still unclear what HTTP verb you are sending in your test. Also, - as @geobreze mentioned - please check that the `@RestController` has a `@RequestMapping` annotation.

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: what should I do ?

Comment: my controller have @RequestMapping annotation

Comment: Does the record you are updating exists?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your application up and running and verify URI resource are in uniform because in
REST API -404 means "Not Found The server can not find the requested resource".

Reference: https://restfulapi.net/http-status-codes/